# Technical error of measurement in between two columns

Tags: r, measurement

I have the following data frame:

```
 data_2
   sex age seca1 chad1  DL alog1 dig1 scifirst1 crimetech1
1    F  19  1800  1797 180    70   69       421        424
2    F  19  1682  1670 167    69   69       421        423
3    F  21  1765  1765 178    80   81       421        423
4    F  21  1829  1833 181    74   72       421        419
5    F  21  1706  1705 170   103  101       439        440
6    F  18  1607  1606 160    76   76       440        439
7    F  19  1578  1576 156    50   48       422        422
8    F  19  1577  1575 156    61   61       439        441
9    F  21  1666  1665 166    52   51       439        441
10   F  17  1710  1716 172    65   65       420        420
11   F  28  1616  1619 161    66   65       426        428
12   F  22  1648  1644 165    58   57       426        429
13   F  19  1569  1570 155    55   54       419        420
14   F  19  1779  1777 177    55   54       422        422
15   M  18  1773  1772 179    70   69       420        419
16   M  18  1816  1809 181    81   80       442        440
17   M  19  1766  1765 178    77   76       425        425
18   M  19  1745  1741 174    76   76       421        423
19   M  18  1716  1714 170    71   70       445        446
20   M  21  1785  1783 179    64   63       446        445
21   M  19  1850  1854 185    71   72       422        421
22   M  31  1875  1880 188    95   95       419        420
23   M  26  1877  1877 186   106  106       420        420
24   M  19  1836  1837 185   100  100       426        423
25   M  18  1825  1823 182    85   85       444        439
26   M  19  1755  1754 174    79   78       420        419
27   M  26  1658  1658 165    69   69       421        421
28   M  20  1816  1818 183    84   83       439        440
29   M  18  1755  1755 175    67   67       429        422
```

I wish to compute the technical error measurement (TEM) between " alog1 " and " dig1 ", which has the following formula:

TEM= √(D/2n)
Where D is the sum of the differences between alog1 and dig1 squared and n is 29

I'm not sure how to compute the sum of the differences squared between the two columns in the first place. Please help.

Comment: Please read some introduction to R. This is very basic: `D <- sum((data_2$alog1 - data_2$dig1)^2)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably with

```
n <- 29
TEM <- sqrt((data_2$alog1-data_2$dig1)^2/2*n)
data_3 <- cbind(data_2, TEM) #To bind it to the table and create the output table 3
```

Check the formula of TEM maybe I didn't understand it correctly.