# Technical error of measurment function R

Tags: r

I have not yet mastered the skill of writing functions and so am asking for help!

I would like to create a function that calculates the technical error of measurement (TEM) and the relative TEM across two columns.

[image]
I have seen previous posts about this, however they don't seem to do what i need them to do...

The first one: [Technical error of measurement (TEM) for 3 or more participants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041102/technical-error-of-measurement-tem-for-3-or-more-participants) is for 3 observers. If you try and apply this with just two observers if gives a different result.

The second one: [Technical error of measurement in between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022182/technical-error-of-measurement-in-between-two-columns) is what i am looking for but i would like it to be a function and not a manual code.

Can someone please help me write this into a function for my data:

```
n <- 23
D <- sum(MHDo1Ana$MHD.o1m1 - MHDo1Ana$MHD.o1m2)
D2 <- D^2
TEM <- sqrt((D2)/2*n)
TEM <- sqrt(((sum(MHDo1Ana$MHD.o1m1 - MHDo1Ana$MHD.o1m2)^2)) / 2 * n)
```

as well as a function for relative TEM?

My data is:

```
  MHD.o1m1 MHD.o1m2
1     46.58    46.77
2     50.66    50.50
3     51.15    50.98
4     46.54    46.16
5     45.78    45.82
6     47.83    47.98
7     43.59    43.66
8     40.27    40.59
9     50.08    50.11
10    47.66    47.69
11    46.11    46.11
12    42.90    43.34
13    38.93    39.14
14    43.89    44.05
15    48.14    48.39
16    46.20    46.11
17    51.34    51.12
18    43.48    43.41
19    46.29    46.14
20    42.26    42.28
21    45.33    45.28
22    47.43    47.23
23    37.37    37.32
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
TEM <- function(df, col1, col2){
    sqrt(((sum(df[, col1] - df[, col2])^2)) / 2 * nrow(df))
}
```

First declare it by pasting it in your console, then use it with (adapted to your dataset):

```
 TEM(MHDo1Ana,  "MHD.o1m1", "MHD.o1m2")
```

[Reproducible example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) below:

```
MHDo1Ana <- read.table(text="  MHD.o1m1 MHD.o1m2
1     46.58    46.77
           2     50.66    50.50
           3     51.15    50.98
           4     46.54    46.16
           5     45.78    45.82
           6     47.83    47.98
           7     43.59    43.66
           8     40.27    40.59
           9     50.08    50.11
           10    47.66    47.69
           11    46.11    46.11
           12    42.90    43.34
           13    38.93    39.14
           14    43.89    44.05
           15    48.14    48.39
           16    46.20    46.11
           17    51.34    51.12
           18    43.48    43.41
           19    46.29    46.14
           20    42.26    42.28
           21    45.33    45.28
           22    47.43    47.23
           23    37.37    37.32")

TEM(MHDo1Ana,  "MHD.o1m1", "MHD.o1m2")
[1] 1.254731
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Vincent. I seem to get an answer of 0 with that function. Do you know what could possibly be the reason? I ran the function and then used it as follows: MHDo1AnaTEM<-TEM(MHDo1Ana)

Comment: `TEM`not `tem`! R is casse-sensitive ;-)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I used TEM and still get 0. Sorry to be a pain. I appreciate your help.

Comment: well, I cleaned by environment and pasted my commands and I still get 1.254731. Could you try the same thing by your side?